# In Java, why do I get "must return a result type of string" issue?

Tags: java, string, methods, return

I'm new at programming with languages. Can anyone explain why do I get that "this method must return a result type of String" issue? And what is the simplest code to achive my goal ? Also what is wrong with my coding?

The goal I want to achive in this method is to return a string if it includes "o" in the first index it should return "o" in the output, as an addition if it includes "z" at the second index of the string, method should return it as "z", if it includes them both, I mean the input string begins with "oz..." method should return a string as "oz".

```
public String startOz(String str) 
{

         if (str.length() <= 1)

         return str;

         else 

         if(str.substring(0, 1).equals("o"))

         if (str.substring(1, 2).equals("z"))
         return "oz";

         else 
         return "o";
```

Thank You.

Comment: You need to properly indent your code so you can understand what your `else`s actually mean.

Comment: Remove all the `else`s!!!

Comment: Using `{}`s will also help you spot these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should re-arrange your code in a more readable manner :

```
public String startOz(String str) 
{
    if (str.length() <= 1) {         
        return str;          
    } else if (str.substring(0, 1).equals("o")) {    
        if (str.substring(1, 2).equals("z")) {
            return "oz";
        } else {
            return "o";
        }
    } // no return value 
}
```

This will let you see immeidately that if the first and second conditions are both false, you have no return value.

You can solve it by adding an `else` clause in the end that would return whatever you wish, or to simply have a return statement in the last line of your method.

Answer (score 1):

**problem:**

```
 if(str.substring(0, 1).equals("o"))
```

You did not specify the return value if the string substring will be equals to "o"

**solution:**

add a return value when you hit that if statement so the compiler will know that method will return something

```
 if(str.substring(0, 1).equals("o"))
     return "value you want to return";
```

Comment: I think that `if` statement goes with the next `if` line (as in, the second line needs to be indented).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new, I highly recommend you use braces.  Bracing your code leads to a revalation:

```
if (str.length() <= 1) {
     return str;
}
else { 
     if(str.substring(0, 1).equals("o")) {
         if (str.substring(1, 2).equals("z")) {
             return "oz";
         }
         else {
             return "o";
         }
     }
     // You need another return statement here OR
 }
 // You need one here.
```

As you can see now, there are instances where your function will return nothing, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String foo(String str)
{
   if(str.substring(0,1).toLowerCase().equals("o"))
   {   
      if(str.substring(1,2).toLowerCase().equals("z")
         return "oz";
      return "o";
   }
   else if(str.length() < 1) return str;

   else return "o";

}
```

Be sure you are returning something if there is an if statement, otherwise it will skip over your line or cause you an error as you are having. This code checks the first character and then the second character. If it is neither it checks the length of the string, if its still none of those, it returns "o".